# How to create a php session variable on click of submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I have a form which uses simple submit button. Now I want to create a php session variable on click of submit button. When someone clicks on submit button a function is called which checks whether that session variable is created or not, if created do something else create new session variable.

example--

```
<input type=submit onclick="sess()">

<script>
  function sess() {
    if (session varaiable exist) {
      do something
    }
    else {
     create new session variable
    }
  }
 </script>
```

this is what I want to achieve.
for this I have using following code --

```
<input type="submit" id="div_session" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#div_session').bind('click', function() {

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'session_write.php',
            data: {cart_items: 'fffg'},
            success: function(data) { $('#cart').html("asd"); alert("cart1");},
            error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }
        });
    });
</script>
```

session_write.php

```
<?
session_start();

$_SESSION['cart_items'] = $_POST['cart_items'];
//echo $_SESSION['cart_items'];
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what ur question is and problem you are facing..could u explain a bit ?

Comment: The first segment seems to expect to check php session values from javascript, which you can't do without extra calls to php files.

Comment: Everytime I see a submit button or `<form>` tag in someone's code that uses AJAX I want to scratch my eyes out.

Comment: And what's your question about this code? Is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])===true) {
 if (isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])===true) {
    //Session is set, do anything here
 } else {
    //Session is not set, setting session now
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = $_POST['cart_items']; //Session is now set
 }
}
?>
```

You will need to set $_POST['cart_items'] to something because it's not declared in this simple script. I hope this helps you!

Comment: but when this condition will be checked--

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])===true)

beacause it will be parsed even before the submit button is clicked.

Comment: When do you want the session to be set, when the button is pressed? Or before the button is pressed?

Comment: I want the session to be set when the button is pressed.

Comment: This will set the session when the button is pressed. if (isset($_POST['submit'])===true) will check whether the button has been pressed, and when it has been pressed, it will check if there is already a session set. If the session is already set, it will do something, and if the session is not set yet, it will set the session.

Comment: when this page will load, it contains form and this validation check. so php statements will be parsed first and it will return false to first condition check. and when the submit button will be clicked, it will be redirected to some other page.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean like, first it checks if the sessions are set, then you click the button and it redirects to another page? I thought you wanted the session to be set when the button was pressed

Comment: I want  exactly what you are thinking. But I think what you are trying to achieve is not right. Because php codes are always parsed first then any other codes. so you can not just put php code below a form to check whether a form button was clicked or not. When the button will be pressed, the page will be redirected to the page where action of form is defined.

If some checks are done even before the event occurs, and when the even occurs then it does not checks the condition written in php code. It can only be done either with juery, ajax, or javascrpt